Cannot find where \IfPackageLoadedTF described
I have found mentions of \IfPackageLoadedTF
in answers to question "Test if a package (or package option) is loaded",
but I cannot find where in documentation it is described.
So far the only result I have found with texdoc is \@ispackageloaded

Have a look at texdoc source2e: https://i.sstatic.net/wiIEzz8Y.png

It is part of the latex format so texdoc source2e has the definition and some documentation, or texdoc ltnews and see ltnews 34.
It could have been in texdoc clsguide for the user level documentation of package level commands, but actually it is not in there currently.

This has now been added to the source for clsguide so should appear at the next release
https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/commit/564abf3f9691e4144526ebeb55101378803e843b

We should sort that; need also to document templates in clsguide so would be a good chance to do both
